# How can i have a SimpleNews signup form as modal/lightbox

Tags: emails, cookies

Is it possible to have the Simplenews sign up form block as a modal - I'd like to present people to the signup a bit more visible than a static block. 
Would i be possible to present the modal when eg. 3 pages have been viewed. Assuming that visitors with 1-2 page views would not be interessted in a newsletter.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, however, modals aren't as simple as clickkng a few things together (at least not before drupal 8 :p).

One way to do it would be to add a counter to user's Session. Increase the counter every time a new page is viewed and once it reaches 3, trigger the display of a modal, for instance by using ctools modal generation api.